Why are similar dataframes showing two different index types?
Updates:
1.I got it to work. I created another unique counter column for both dataframes and then used merge instead of concat
terminal_price['counter'] = np.arange(terminal_price.shape[0])
terminal_pnl['counter'] = np.arange(terminal_pnl.shape[0])
pnl_vs_price_df = terminal_price.merge(terminal_pnl, how = 'inner', on='counter')

Now I get the df I wanted:

Sorry for wasting everyone's time.....should have used merge before. However, I am curious if there's a more direct way to do this than what I did above. Not sure why df indexes should be of two different types...and even if they are, could I make them the same? Earlier, when I tried to concat on the existing indices, it gave me an empty df.
Updates:
@wjandrea - thanks for the feedback.
I'm not able to reproduce the source of the dataframes - as that comes from a simulation code which is quite massive. However, in terms of a minimum reproducible example, I hope this helps:

I re-ran the simulation with just 5 time steps so it's easier to visualize.
Both the dataframes are shown. Now from what I can tell, these df's are similar, they look the same too. But when I do a concat, I get the dataframes stacked on top of each other...instead of columns being placed adjacent to each other against a common index.

Here's what it looks like:

I also tried merge against the common index  - that gave me nothing. This leads me to believe that even the indexes of the two df's look the same in the picture.....they are actually not - going back to my original post below. One of the indices is an object, the other is a RangeIndex.
I'm trying to create a graph of PnL vs price from a simulation of a call option. I have to extract data from the results of the simulation. I wanted to combine the extracted data into a single dataframe, but my resulting dataframe does not join them. I found out that the index of the two extract dataframes is different... what's going on?
In the screenshot below, I see the terminal_price dataframe having an index type object. The other dataframe of PnL values, however, is a RangeIndex. I checked, and both the df's have the same dimensions and are of the same class; i.e. pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. So I'm not sure exactly what's going on here. Why do I get two different index types? I will try to convert the data extracts into pure series and then convert back into a concatenated dataframe, but in the meantime, why is this even happening?
I'm not able to show the entire working (just too much to copy paste), but here's how I extracted the relevant data:
terminal_price = dhedge_strat['path'].iloc[-1:,].T
terminal_price.rename(columns = {999 : 'term_price'}, inplace=True)
terminal_pnl = pd.DataFrame(dhedge_err_['hedge_error']).reset_index()



Make a [mre]. This code doesn't show where terminal_price's index comes from. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples. And everything should be provided as text, not a picture.

Regarding "I will try to convert the data extracts into pure series and then convert back into a concatenated dataframe", that probably won't help because if you take a column out of a df, it keeps the df's index, but maybe you're going to do it another way, IDK.

Regarding "both the df's have the same dimensions and are of the same class", that doesn't really tell you anything. Pandas dfs support modifying the index.

if you resolved your problem then describe it as answer below. And you can mark you answer as accepted. And later you can upvote it.

A counter column? Why not just reset the index on terminal_price so it matches terminal_pnl?

BTW, to notify a user, use an @-tag in a comment. An @-tag in a question (or answer) doesn't do anything. I just happened to see this question again on the front page.

The edits don't really clarify the problem. Thanks for making a smaller example, but what I'm really looking for is where terminal_price's index comes from (like I said). It seems like the source df's column names are strings even though they're numeric, but IDK why that would be. Then when you do .T, the column names become terminal_price's index.

To answer the question in the title, they're showing two different index types because they have two different index types, as you saw.

Updates: I got it to work. I created another unique counter column for both dataframes and then used merge instead of concat
terminal_price['counter'] = np.arange(terminal_price.shape[0])
terminal_pnl['counter'] = np.arange(terminal_pnl.shape[0])
pnl_vs_price_df = terminal_price.merge(terminal_pnl, how = 'inner', on='counter')

I'm sure there's a better way to do this.
